# NSImage does not Change for Light/Dark Appearances

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview, macos-darkmode

I am developing a Mac Cocoa app. And I have a set of images to adopt for both light and dark modes.

I followed the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances

In `viewWillLayout()`, I set up an image for a view like so:

```
nsImgaeView.image = NSImage(named: "Image") // Does not change after toggling light/dark mode
```

But`NSImage(named: "Image")` simply does not change its appearance after me toggling light/dark mode in System Preferences.

I am sure that the code was invoked because:

```
nsImgaeView.image = NSImage(named: "Another_Image") // Changes to another image after toggling
```

Restarting the app does make it change its appearance. I guess it is because the system caches the image after the initial load?

Comment: More likely you used CGLayer and not updated it with correct image. Your code doesn't say much about "someView.image".  If it's NSImageView it will work. If you render image manually -> check for issue there

Comment: Yes, someView is of type ```NSImageView```

Comment: Check your image in asset catalogue.